# simple firebase search user

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a question. I am trying to implement search into my app, and when a user enters a username into the searchbar and then clicks search, if that user exists, display it in the tableview. I have some code Im using now, but I want to avoid fetching all users from firebase, I only want to query the username inputed to the searchbar, not all users. Anything is helpful. 
My database structure: 
[image]

My code:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let useri = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (_, one) in useri {
                let newUser = usera()
                if let username = one["Username"] as? String {
                    if username.lowercased().contains((searchBar.text?.lowercased())!) {

                if  let name = one["Full Name"] as? String, let uid = one["uid"] as? String {
                    newUser.name = name
                    newUser.uid = uid
                    newUser.username = username
                    self.users.append(newUser)
                }
                }
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableViewSearchUser.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
ref.child("users").child(userid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, 
                                                    with: { snapshot in ...
```

Where userid is the is of the user you are looking for?

Comment: If we know the userid no need to search. Question is about to search.